# Malformed Character escape and python expandvars for user desktop folders

Tags: python, os.path

When using os.path.expandvars in Python; I haven't had much of an issue accessing Document folders or AppData folders, but when attempting to to access a Desktop folder the system throws the following error.

Is there another variable that is needed or is the double escape "\ \" really needed for the desktop vs other locations?

```
if os.path.exists(os.path.join(os.path.expandvars("%userprofile%"),"Desktop"))==True:
print("yes")
               #No issue with this: returns True

if os.path.exists(os.path.join(os.path.expandvars("%userprofile%"),"Desktop\NF"))==True:
                                                                   ^
```

`SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 7-8: malformed \N character escape
          #Need help understanding why an escape is needed for this location`
                                                                  ^

`if os.path.exists(os.path.join(os.path.expandvars("%userprofile%"),"Documents\Videos"))==True:
    print("yes")
    #No issue with this: returns True`

The desktop folder NF does exist and existed prior to attempting to access with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python uses the \N sequence to denote that a unicode character identified by it's name:

```
print('\N{LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A}')
A
```

Consequently, if a string contains the sequence `'\N'` which is not starting a `'\N{name}'` escape, a `SyntaxError` is raised unless the `'\N'` is escaped:

```
'Deskstop\\New'
```

or is part of a raw string

```
r'Deskstop\New'
```

or, if the backslash is a path separator, replaced with a forward slash

```
'Desktop/New'
```

I suspect `os.path.join` or its `pathlib` equivalent will handle this situation correctly if used like this:

```
os.path.join(os.path.expandvars("%userprofile%"),"Desktop", "New")
```

but I can't be 100% certain as I'm not on a Windows machine.